# Can't debug Artifactory issue, can't start up, stuck with 500 error

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, javabeans, artifactory

**What I am Doing**

I am trying to set up Artifactory. Whenever I try and get my service up, it's at a `500` error and I can't fix it.

---

**What I've Tried**

I have tried many solutions online, mainly searching for and trying the different solutions such as:

- `'(o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:194) - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null'`

**And**

- `'[art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:96) - Application could not be initialized: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')'`

---

**Some More Information**

```
Version:  6.13.1                                  
 Revision: 61301900                            
 Artifactory Home: '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory'
 HA Node ID: '[REDACTED]'

openjdk version "1.8.0_232"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)  

status  500  
message "Artifactory failed to initialize: check Artifactory logs for errors."
```

---

I don't know why this is happening and if anyone could recommend suggestions, I would try them all.

```
2020-02-18 15:45:39,797 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'remote' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/binary-store-client-3.4.8.jar!/
2020-02-18 15:45:40,251 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.a.f.t.j.s.S3JetS3tBinaryProvider:530) - Connecting to S3 endpoint: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
2020-02-18 15:45:40,956 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:254) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xrayServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addon-xray-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/xray/XrayServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activePrincipalTokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activePrincipalTokenStoreImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-core-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/security/auth/ActivePrincipalTokenStoreImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uploadService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
2020-02-18 15:45:40,975 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:96) - Application could not be initialized: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:67)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:92)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xrayServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addon-xray-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/xray/XrayServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activePrincipalTokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activePrincipalTokenStoreImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-core-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/security/auth/ActivePrincipalTokenStoreImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uploadService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:254)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:149)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activePrincipalTokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activePrincipalTokenStoreImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-core-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/security/auth/ActivePrincipalTokenStoreImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uploadService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activePrincipalTokenStore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activePrincipalTokenStoreImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-core-6.13.1.jar!/org/artifactory/security/auth/ActivePrincipalTokenStoreImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uploadService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)


... removed cause 30k char limit but same errors...




 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
            ... 101 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.loadFromEC2InstanceDataNew(AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.java:141)
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.loadFromEC2InstanceDataNew(AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.java:160)
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.S3JetS3tBinaryProvider.createCredentials(S3JetS3tBinaryProvider.java:479)
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.S3JetS3tBinaryProvider.initialize(S3JetS3tBinaryProvider.java:135)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.build(BinaryProviderFactory.java:98)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.build(BinaryProviderFactory.java:86)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.build(BinaryProviderFactory.java:86)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.build(BinaryProviderFactory.java:93)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.build(BinaryProviderFactory.java:86)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.builder.BinaryProviderFactory.buildProviders(BinaryProviderFactory.java:75)
            at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.manager.BinaryProviderManagerImpl.<init>(BinaryProviderManagerImpl.java:115)
            at org.artifactory.storage.db.binstore.service.BinaryServiceImpl.initialize(BinaryServiceImpl.java:187)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
            ... 113 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6cb92d33; line: 1, column: 2]
            at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedParser.java:1198)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:485)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2770)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1542)
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.parseEC2InstanceDataNew(AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.java:183)
            at org.artifactory.addon.filestore.type.jets3t.s3.AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.loadFromEC2InstanceDataNew(AWSEC2IAMSessionCredentialsNew.java:138)
            ... 131 common frames omitted
    2020-02-18 15:45:41,372 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:194) - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null
```

Comment: You look like you've got a typo in an XML file - perhaps spring.xml?

Comment: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/145 ?

Comment: Thanks Amaud but after double checking, my primary and secondary nodes seem to have the correct ha-node.properties files. Even changed them a bit and did a restart but no changes.

And to stdunbar, I don't see any typos in any XML files used.

Thanks y'all for the suggestions.

Comment: I have a chef cookbook where when i converge our artifactory code, i can get to the GUI successfully.
But if I make a cluster with terraform, I can't get to the GUI and instead receive a 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

Check your binarystore.xml.

Seems like you have a property named instanceMetadataUrl and this url should resolve json, but it resolves xml. Probably error page.

You could also turn on debug on this section of the Artifactory application by changing the logback.xml file. 
Add this section under one of the loggers:

```
<logger name="org.artifactory.addon.filestore">
        <level value="debug"/>
</logger>
```

This will give you much more information about what is going on.
When the issue is resolved, return the logback.xml to it's original state.

Answer (score 1):

So the error was my  in binarystore.xml did not match the instance's. Once that was fixed, I got the UI and everything is running and fine. Wish the error warning was more accurate. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I have the same problem, how do I fix it?